# Chartjs not zooming out on x-axis

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

I have used the zoom plugin for zooming my chart and it was quite useful but I am getting some really difficulty in zooming out. On my x-axis there are dates and I am zooming only the x-axis. If I zoom in and then zoom out it is not doing and showing the chart back to its position however if I simply plot the counting numbers along side the x-axis it zoom out successfully. I have searched but nothing helps in this regard.

Another suggestion I want is can I have a scroll depend on the zoom? like on x-axis when I zoom in graph go out of the canvas total width and we cannot see the future points. So can I have the scroll that increase the scroll as the zoom and we can scroll the graph? Or another suggestion is may be we can have a drag option like drag the chart to the position like we move and pull the chart to and fro.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer oh sorry actually i post it from the other forum, where i posted and was not aware of it.